# Codeigniter Datatables / table add data

Tags: javascript, json, codeigniter, jquery, datatables

i am newbie in web programming and datatables and i am trying to add new data to my tables using fnAddData() but it not work

here is my code

```
$('#btn_ubahbj').click( function() {

                //inisialisasi table upproses

                Otableupproses=$('#tableupproses').dataTable( {
                'sDom': 't',
                "bServerSide": false,
                "sServerMethod": "POST",
                "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
                        aoData.push( { "name": "idbom", "value": window.id_bom } );
                    },
                "sAjaxSource": "<?=base_url()?>index.php/master_bj/ambilbomproses",
                "sAjaxDataProp": "callback",
                "bDestroy": true,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "aoColumns":    [
                                    { "sTitle": "ID Proses",   "mDataProp": "id_proses_produksi"},
                                    { "sTitle": "Nama Proses",  "mDataProp": "nama"},
                                    { "sTitle": "Lama Proses", "mDataProp": "waktu"},
                                    { "sTitle": "Jumlah Mesin",  "mDataProp": "jumlah_mesin"},
                                ]
                } );

            } );


$('#btnuptambahproses').click(

                Otableupproses.fnAddData( [$('#prosesupbj').val(),$("#prosesupbj option:selected").text(),$('#txtuplamaproses').val(),$('#txtupjmlmesin').val()]
                );
             });
```

my controller name master_bj

```
function ambilbomproses()
{
    $idbom= $this->input->post('idbom');
    $res['dataproses']=$this->bom_punya_proses_model->getbomproses($idbom);

    echo json_encode(array("callback" => $res['dataproses']));
}
```

how can i dinamically add new row ?
i use fnAddData() it not work because i get data from json 
please help

my model class name bom_punya_proses_model

```
function getbomproses($idbom)
{
    $sql=   "SELECT proses_produksi_punya_bom.id_proses_produksi, proses_produksi.nama, proses_produksi_punya_bom.waktu, proses_produksi_punya_bom.jumlah_mesin
            FROM proses_produksi_punya_bom
            INNER JOIN proses_produksi ON proses_produksi_punya_bom.id_proses_produksi = proses_produksi.id_proses_produksi
            WHERE proses_produksi_punya_bom.id_bom =  '".$idbom."'";
    $result=  $this->db->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows() > 0){
            return $result->result_array();
    }else
        return false;
}
```

no problem with my query and controller , because the json has been performed correctly , but the problem is when i try to add new row data to table ,

Comment: do you use a model for your queries? if yes post the model method please

Comment: i update it please help , @okok

Comment: array from database already success fill the table , but what i need is to dinamically add new row to table @okok

Comment: sorry dude i do not know datatables :/

Answer (score 0):

Your model does not appear to be using the active records portion of the codeigniter framework at all.

Check the tutorial on the CI website and have a look at the active record help page at :
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: yes sir but it woking properly , doesnt matter with the model , but the problem is when i dynamically add new row with fnadddata()